# Mixing search indexes using the Amazon Product Advertising API

Tags: amazon-product-api

How do you run a search using two and only two search indexes on the Amazon Product Advertising API, like DVD and Books.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. You can either:

- Use the **blended** index, which will search everything, or
- Submit two ItemSearchRequests, one for the Books index and another for the DVDs index. This is why Amazon lets you submit multiple requests in a single API call (using the SOAP versions).